# Is every normed space metrizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

Is every normed space (infinity dimensional) metrizable ?

Comment: $d(x,y) = \lVert x - y \rVert$, but I'm guessing there's something more to your question?

Comment: Is every hot dog a dog?

Comment: Ok but if i have some topological vector space then this space( not always) is metrizable ?

Comment: @user577360 right, you can check Munkres' book for metrizability conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, every norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ induces a metric via

$$d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert$$

regardless of dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Every norm on a vector space $V$ induces a metric on $V$ by defining $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. But of course, not every metric space is of this form; many are not vector spaces and have no norm.

There are also metric vector spaces that are not normable (their topology (though induced by a metric) cannot be induced by a metric from a norm, e.g. $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ in the product topology, or the spaces $\ell^p$ for $0 < p <1$.

There also are topological vector spaces, also locally convex ones, that are not metrisable at all (so a fortiori don't have a compatible norm). One example is $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$, the set of all functions from the reals to itself, in the pointwise (aka product) topology.